# echo PDO query as string in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Basically I am trying to return the total number of columns that correspond to a given criteria:

```
$exec = $link->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `requests` WHERE language='PHP'");
$result = $exec->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $result[0];
```

However, the above does not return anything but the SQL query is correct since it returns a value when executed in phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you explicitly used the flag `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`, you need to point on the associative index it returns. I'd suggest put an alias on the `count()`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM `requests` WHERE language='PHP'
```

Then access it after fetching:

```
echo $result['total'];
```

Another way would be to use `->fetchColumn()`:

```
$count = $exec->fetchColumn();
echo $count;
```

Comment: I actually never thought of looking into the query itself. Thank you for your time. Will accept it as soon as possible.

Comment: @schmitsz pointing into index `[0]` should have given you an undefined index actually, so you should turn on error reporting always. im glad this helped

Comment: A bad habit of mine is often doing `error_reporting(0);` right after the opening tag.